# navbar link is hidden when using mobile other resolution

Tags: css, mobile, hyperlink, navbar, hidden

I'm trying to set up a navbar with bootstrap 4.

It works when I'm on PC. But when I change the resolution to put me in mobile or tablet view, the links are no longer visible, I don't understand why

[image]

And next :

[image]

I don't understand what's wrong ..
This is my code :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  <style>
      html, body{
          padding-top: 30px;
      }
      .navbar {
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
      }
  </style>
{% endblock %}


{% block navbar %}

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-bg">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-row-reverse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Connexion</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the bootstrap mobile menu behavior.
As you can see, your navbar has the class `navbar-collapse`, `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-row-reverse" id="navbarColor01">`.
It collapse the content of the navbar for smaller device sizes.

If your window/device size is small enough, the navbar collapses and the button is visible, or not (in your case). The icon/color is missing.
But if you press the empty space, your menu is showing up.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" 
aria-expanded="false" 
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
```

[image]

A possible solution would be, remove the button and the collapse behavior like this:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-bg">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="flex-row-reverse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Connexion</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Or change some more styling and use the button/collapsing behavior.